# Is it still true that zenddebugger only supports non-thread-safe PHP?

Tags: php, zend-debugger

This is the case according to a thread in 2009 [here](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=1742),

is it still the case now?

Anyone managed to make it work with thread safe PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is still the case - the recommended way on Windows is FCGI which runs non-TS PHP.

Unfortunately, it's impossible to make non-TS module to work with TS PHP - data structures are different, so even it one could hack it so it would load it would immediately crash.